# Improve compression ratio with Delphi 6 app that uses the Windows AVIFile functions?

Tags: delphi, winapi, video-encoding, avi

I have a Delphi 6 app that makes movies from an incoming video and audio stream from a robot.  The PC receives the video stream as a series of JPEG frames and the audio as blocks of PCM audio data.  I am using the Windows AVIFile functions (AVIStreamCreate, etc.) to create the movie.  For the choice of video compressor I use the AVISaveOptions() function and let the user select one of the available compressors from those available on their system.  For example: Microsoft Video 1, Cinepak Code by Radius, etc.  Note several of the other available ones, like Microsoft H.263 or H.261 fail with AVIERR_BADFORMAT errors so I could not test with them.  The audio is compressed using the GSM 6.10 compressor.

The problem is I can't seem to get near the compression ratio that I can using a tool like Adobe Premiere for comparison.  Note, I am aware that Premiere is compressing using a different overall process than mine, and to a different file format like MPEG, or Quicktime, etc.  But I would like to get a comparable compression ratio if I can.

No matter which compressor I choose from AVISaveOptions(), and no matter how low I crank the available compression quality settings for the compressor (for example, Temporal Quality Ratio & Compression Quality for Microsoft Video 1), a minutes worth of video always ends up creating an AVI file of approximately 14MB in size.  For comparison, the file I can create using Adobe Premiere is less than 1 MB in size and looks about the same *visual* quality (in other words, good enough for my purposes.  I don't care about actual quality loss here.).

If I examine the file output from my usage of the Windows AVI API I see that none of the settings I change with the compressor affect the frame rate.  It is always identical to the input frame rate. Now if necessary obviously I can drop frames on the input side, but that would be a bit messy since it is synced to the audio and I'd like to avoid that if I could.

But more importantly is the Data rate.  I can never get that below approximately 2.3 kbps no matter how low I crank the compressor settings down.  The videos I create with Premiere, and other videos I've played with that have a healthy file size to duration ratio, are all about 1.2 kbps.

Overall the difference in between the file size of my AVI files and the ones I create with Premiere or other people have sent to me that compress well is **10 to 1**.  Therefore my compression ratio is 10 times worse than other video files, and those other files have no unpleasant difference in their video quality.

What can I do to get a comparable compression ratio?

**UPDATE**: The reply by David Heffernan contains a fast solution that worked for me.  I am highlighting it because it also contains a **vital licensing warning** too.  For those of you, like me, that want to make it as convenient for your users as possible to use the XVid codec, read the article below.  It contains instructions on how to *re-use* a user's compressor choice, along with their chosen compression configuration choices, in future sessions without bothering the user again:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580739.aspx

For the curious, the change in size from my previous output AVI file size to the file created using the XVid codec was 12.231 MB to 632 **KB** and the video quality was more than reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The truly simple answer is to install the [XVID](http://www.xvid.org) encoder. None of the codecs that are supplied with Windows are fit for your purpose. XVID is both high quality and free.

Regarding distribution and licensing implications, the [XVID FAQ](http://www.xvid.org/FAQ.42.0.html) has this to say:

> **Can I distribute Xvid together with my proprietary program?**
>
> If your program calls Xvid functionality upon run-time it’s a derived work and hence, the terms of the GPL apply to the work as a whole including your program. So no, you cannot distribute Xvid together with your proprietary program then. If you want to distribute, you’ll have to publish your program under the GPL as well. That also requires e.g. the provision of the full apps source code. Refer to the GPL license text for more information.
>
> **We don’t link to Xvid at all, just call through the VfW interface upon run-time – can we distribute with our proprietary software?**
>
> No. It doesn’t matter in which way you link to Xvid or what you count as linking and what not. The GPL doesn’t focus on the term ‘linking’ at all but rather requires combined/derived works to be published as a whole under the terms of the GPL. Basically any two (or more) pieces make up a combined work when they are distributed for use in combination. Hence, if your program calls upon Xvid functionality at run-time it would make up a derived work - no matter how you technically implement the calls to Xvid. If you don’t want to publish your program under the GPL then refrain from distributing it in combination with Xvid.

What this means for you is that you could only distribute XVID with your program if your program is also licensed under the GPL. But it is perfectly fine for you to suggest to your users that they obtain XVID for themselves.

Comment: Thanks David. Can I install that for a user in my install program, or is that something they have to do manually due to user privileges, etc.?  Also, what's the story behind your new avatar pic?  Is that an Android thing?

Comment: I'm not sure about distributing XVID. I know we don't do that and just suggest that our users do so. That's never been an issue for us. I believe it is GPL licensed. Avatar? It's a moshling named Oddie.

Comment: Double thanks on the licensing clarification.  Just finished downloading and testing and it creates a nice small file.  I'll just tell the user to download the XVid codec in my app's first time setup wizard and tell them to configure it for smallest file size.  After that I can save their compressor choice with the configured options and re-use them in the future automatically.